# W3WP is running slow

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-4, w3wp

I have a very unusual problem with W3WP process (IIS Worker Process). It is not taking enough memory from my CPU to run faster. It is impacting my development work as it is taking way to long to pull up a local website. When I start the website from my localhost, W3WP start at roughly 50MB and takes nearly 10 min to spike upto 100MB.

Is there a way to make W3WP run fatser?

I am using a 64bit 3.4GHZ Quad Core i5 CPU with 8GB RAM. OS Windows 7 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Profile it and figure out what is slow.

Comment: I doubt very much that the problem is with IIS.  Much more likely that the website that you are trying to pull up is either slow itself, or is taking time to compile.  By default, .NET dynamically creates assemblies for ASP.NET websites when they are first visited.

Comment: @ChrisShain This is a SiteCore site. Typically the sites with a CMS runs slow (for the first time) as it compiles tons of classes for every go. This might impact the responsiveness of the site, but my question is why it is not picking all the available resources for computation (like physical memory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to IIS settings and changed the 'Worker Process'/'Change .Net Framework Version' from 2.XX to 4.XX. Also I have a dedicated app pool for my application and stopped all other applications. These changes made things a lot better that what it was.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.NET Profiler` too see the slow methods.
Also you can change resource limits ( CPU , Memory , ... ) in advanced application pool settings.

Comment: I went to IIS settings and changed the 'Worker Process'/'Change .Net Framework Version' from 2.XX to 4.XX. Also I have a dedicated app pool for my application and stopped all other applications. These changes made things a lot better that what it was.